# code from black hat python runs forever?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code in this pastebin link [here](http://pastebin.com/E98XChyU) is from the Black Hat Python Book, It's a great book but I've been having a lot of problems with the code because I couldn't simply copy and paste the code to my ide which meant hours of rewriting because of errors.

I have finally finished writing the code and hopefully for the last time am experiencing an error. The code in the pastebin link always runs forever. It doesn't return an error, it just indefinitely runs. In the command prompt I type:

```
bhp.py -t google.com -p 80
```

and that runs forever. 
Also if I type

```
echo -ne "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com -p 80" | bhp.py -t www.google.com -p 80
```

that returns "[*] Exception! Exiting!"

hopefully that can provide some insight into what the problem is. I am currently on a windows 10 laptop too if that can help. Thanks for helping

EDIT: the author used linux

Comment: Please copy the *essential* code that causes problems into your question. Don't provide a link to a random website.

Comment: @Evert it is a pastebin link

Comment: It's not about where the link leads to (that's what's meant with "random"). It's about having to go to a separate website to find the code. Keep all essentials to the question in one place.

Comment: You don't need to type the source code in, it is available for download from http://www.nostarch.com/download/BHP-Code.zip. You should check out this page too: https://www.nostarch.com/blackhatpython

Comment: Just downloaded that and I am still getting the same error...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide us a [mcve].  (Often, the act of trimming your code to just the part that's failing will reveal the problem, saving you a round trip to Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I am unsure as to which part of the code is failing

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm on windows 10 and the author used Linux?

Comment: I highly recommend Eric Lippert's “[How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)”.  It's a short article (one of several good ones at the bottom of the Help Center's “[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”), and it covers topics like isolating errors very well.

Comment: Which of the programs from the book is this? Give Chapter and example numbers. You are making it very hard for anyone to help you by requiring people to do a huge amount of work to discover what your question actually is.

Comment: @jwpfox It's the code from chapter 2 and the book called the program "bhpnet.py" though the downloaded versions name is "bhnet.py"

Answer (score 0):

Here are some insights :

First using pastebin you can click 'raw' link to get the code properly : http://pastebin.com/raw/E98XChyU

Didn't test, but it seems correct.

Anyway, your problem is in this function : `client_sender(buffer)`

At the end of this function, replace the `except` handler by :

```
except Exception as e:
    # catch exceptions more properly, you can still do some "homework"
    print("[*] Exception : %s" % e)               
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
    # teardown the connection                  
    client.close()
```

This will give you more information.